# rspec cant find id on FactoryGirl created model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following model:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :team_b_id, :team_a_id

  def description
    Team.find(team_a_id).name + " vs " + Team.find(team_b_id).name
  end
end
```

for which I wrote this test:

```
describe Game do
  ...
  it "returns game description" do
    game = FactoryGirl.create(:game) do
      team_a_id = FactoryGirl.create(:team, name: "Team A").id
      team_b_id = FactoryGirl.create(:team, name: "Team B").id
    end
    game.description.should == team_a.name + " vs " + team_b.name
  end
end
```

Validation is not working because it:

> "Cannot find Team with id 1"

These are the factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :game do |f|
    f.team_a_id { 1 }
    f.team_b_id { 2 }
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :team do |f|
    f.name { "Team Name" }
  end
end
```

Comment: ruby 4, factory_girl_rails gem

Comment: you already define `f.team_a_id {1}` and `f.team_b_id {2}` so when you call `FactoryGirl.create(:team, name: "Team A")` it will automatically take those two define value so it has both team_a_id and team_b_id so nno question on validation failed here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the error is probably happening inside the description function, because you're not setting the id correctly.

Try changing your code to the following:

```
team_a_id = FactoryGirl.create(:team, name: "Team A").id
team_b_id = FactoryGirl.create(:team, name: "Team B").id

game = FactoryGirl.create(:game, team_a_id: team_a_id, team_b_id: team_b_id)
```

This should set the id's in the game model.